# How best to convert this Jar-based Applet to run Locally?

Tags: java, conversion, applet, java-web-start

Increased Java security polices have meant that my students can no longer run some incredibly useful (but old) Java applets in modern browsers.

I've been able to directly download the associated Jar files etc., but don't know how best to run them locally (ie with the fewest security problems). Either:
1. run them as a local applet ?
2. try to run the jar files as a local java application ?  (avoids browser issues altogether?)

How exactly do I do either solution?

The applet current reads:

Can I somehow use JavaWebStart to launch this applet/application?

Hope someone can help, Thanks